# gnuplot: floating terminal width ? fixed terminal height

Tags: graph, size, gnuplot, margin

Can you tell us how to make the chart with all headings and captions fit into the fixed vertical size and the horizontal size is floating?

If I set small fixed image sizes, some axes captions disappear, and if I set large fixed image sizes, then there is an empty space on the sides.

And I want you to be able to specify the height of the image and gnuplot will determine for itself what its width must be to fit everything you need.

For example (margin - empty space, but on the right, the inscription didn't fit:

```
set terminal pngcairo notransparent enhanced font "Calibri, 15" fontscale 1.0 size 800, 800; set zeroaxis;
```

[image]

Comment: Automatically is likely not possible. Every image is unique. There is a `set rmargin` command that lets you set the right margin. Looks like you will need `set rmargin 8` or 9 if that bottom number is 0.0000001.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, gnuplot does not automatically provide enough space for long numbers in the colorbox.
Since you have a logarithmic scale from `0.0000001` to `0.1`, you might want to consider to display your numbers in a different format, i.e. from `10^-7` to `10^-1`.

**Code:**

```
### no long numbers in colorbox
reset session

set colorbox
set palette rgb 33,13,10
set xrange [-7:-1]
set cbrange [1e-7:0.1]
set logscale cb
set format cb "10^{%T}"

plot '+' u 1:1:(10**$1) w l lw 3 palette z notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: The use of a logarithmic scale is of course advisable, and I did so after

The problem was caused by the fact that gnuplot failed to correctly fit the chart into the specified canvas size, which we would like to see.